# using capifony to copy remote database to local

Tags: symfony, capistrano, capifony

In the [capifony docs](http://capifony.org/cookbook/working-with-databases.html) it shows that you can copy the remote database to a local copy. I don't know enough ruby to understand the error message though:

```
`database:dump:remote' is only run for servers matching {:roles=>:db, :only=>{:primary=>true}}, but no servers matched
```

I have this in my `deploy.rb`:

```
role :web,        "{my-production-ip}"                         
role :app,        "{my-production-ip}", :primary => true
```

What do i need to do to work in the `db` role?

Comment: Only `role :db,        "{my-production-ip}", :primary => true` imho according to the capistrano DSL docs…

Comment: @nietonfir do you know where i can find docs on the database.yml file? Is that suppose to be generated for you?

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow you. What `database.yml` file are you talking about?

Comment: @nietonfir i keep seeing mentions of a `database.yml` file in the capistrano docs. I was able to run the command but it errored out because it was using an incorrect database name. I don't know where to specify which database to use. [Reference of said database.yml file.](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/preparing-your-application/)

Comment: Shouldn't be needed. I can execute `database:dump:remote` with the default capifony config without any problems in a multistage environment.